# How do I open the Uniface debugger in an open program via a shortcut?

Tags: debugging, uniface

I would like to start the debug mode via a shortcut in an open Uniface program.

How do I do that in Uniface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the debugger of Uniface with the keyboard shortcut STR-Y.